# Javascript class attributes loaded async in constructor?

Tags: asynchronous, coffeescript

I'm struggling with JavaScript async patterns to achieve this :

I have a class (I'm using CoffeeScript) with some attributes initialized in the constructor from some async calls. Then I have some methods that require these attributes to work. Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do :

```
# Class definition
class window.MyClass
  constructor: ->
    @attr = ... # loaded with an ajax call or whatever

  myMethod: ->
    console.log @attr

# User code
c = new MyClass()
c.myMethod() # should console.log the value loaded asynchronously
```

So the issue will be that when `myMethod()` is called, the async call hasn't finished yet.

I know a few solutions, however they imply moving the method call inside a callback (or a then function with promises). I want to avoid this to be able to call this method from click handlers or something else totally unrelated.

Also note that I can't move the async call inside my method since I will probably have several methods using the attribute, and I don't want to load the `attr` at each call, but only in the constructor.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to do this. Not sure if it's very clean, but it works and fits my needs.

After loading asynchronously my `attr` value, I dispatch an event `MyClassReady`.
In my constructor, I've added a first listener to `MyClassReady` that sets an attribute `ready` to true.

Then, in `myMethod`, I wrapped my code in a function. Then I call this function if `ready` is true, otherwise I bind this function to the `MyClassReady` event.

The result looks like this :

```
# Class definition
class window.MyClass
  constructor: ->
    # Async load of `attr`
    self = this
    loadAttr (val) ->
      self.attr = val
      window.dispatchEvent new Event 'MyClassReady'

    window.addEventListener 'MyClassReady', ->
      self.ready = true

  myMethod: ->
    self = this
    callback = ->
      console.log self.attr

    # If the attrs are already loaded
    if @ready
      callback()
    else
      window.addEventListener 'MyClassReady', ->
        callback()

# User code
c = new MyClass()
c.myMethod() # this will wait until attr is loaded
```

I think it would be nice to move this code to a library, however with all the `self = this` stuff it seems complicated.

**Edit:** note that custom events aren't supported by IE...